# Flatpak doesn't find existing apps on Flathub for installation

Tags: debian, flatpak

I'm using Flatpak 1.10.7 on Debian 11 (32 bit) and it can't seem to find anything on Flathub for me to install.

I set up Flathub according to their instructions and then run e.g. `$ flatpak install flathub tv.kodi.Kodi`:

```
Looking for matches…
error: Nothing matches tv.kodi.Kodi in remote flathub
```

That's just plain wrong, according to their own website: https://flathub.org/apps/details/tv.kodi.Kodi

Doing a search `flatpak search vlc` similarly results in zero matches. And that's an application I *know* I've installed successfully using flatpak before, on this very system.

I've tried following all their setup instructions, I've re-added the remote, I've run flatpak repair, but it doesn't make any difference. I don't know... Flatpak seems to be nothing but trouble for me lately. What's wrong this time?

Either way, Flatpak seems needlessly complicated and difficult to get working. Should I be using something else in Debian? Installing Kodi directly from the official repo doesn't really work either since it segfaults immediately, so I want the flexibility to be able to install and explore different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both kodi and vlc is not built for your architecture, which is i386. On the regular flathub site they do not show which architectures it's built for but they do on the beta page.

https://beta.flathub.org/apps/tv.kodi.Kodi , built for x86_64

https://beta.flathub.org/apps/org.videolan.VLC , built for aarch64, x86_64

Like with other package managers they usually don't show you, by default, the package if it's not built for your specific architecture.

Comment: The [instructions for Debian](https://flatpak.org/setup/Debian) do not mention that as a necessary step before installing apps. Considering the linked issue was also [fixed in 2018](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1339), what makes you believe it is required?

Comment: When searching for my error on google, this question shows up. I thought this was the answer, but on closer inspection it seems like your error is that you use an unsupported architecture. The kodi manifest on flathub is only built for x86_64, and not your architecture i386.

On the https://beta.flathub.org/apps/tv.kodi.Kodi page they start to show the available architectures in the frontend, where I found it.

Comment: Thanks! It figures that you'd have to know about, and navigate to, their beta site just to be presented with the bare minimum and absolutely essential information, invalidating everything claimed on the main site and in the CLI. At least it's in line with the rest of the Flatpak experience, I suppose... Still, it doesn't explain how I could install the exact same app on the exact same machine at an earlier date, nor the absence of VLC. Surely VLC is not constrained to 64 bit? ... [Turns out it is](https://beta.flathub.org/apps/org.videolan.VLC). Really? It sounds like a joke... ...Why?

Comment: I completely missed that you also updated your answer, mentioning VLC. But I can't wrap my head around Flatpak/Flathub at all anymore — I'm absolutely positive I installed VLC earlier, and 32 bit Kodi as late as July 2022 using Flathub. This all seems very suspicious and unreliable.